# Left Singular Vectors and Right Singular Vectors in SVD

Tags: matrix-factorisation

[image: SVD Diagram]

Figure 7: The canonical diagram of the SVD decomposition of a matrix M. The columns of U are the orthonormal left singular vectors; Σ is a diagonal matrix of singular values; and the rows of V^⊤ are the orthonormal right singular vectors. The dashed areas are padding.

What do left singular vectors and right singular vectors mean here? My understanding of matrices is not the greatest.